# Flatpak doesen't install on kubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, kubuntu, flatpak

When I try to install flatpak I get this error

````
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package flatpak is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  xdg-desktop-portal

E: Package 'flatpak' has no installation candidate```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that the universe repository is enabled.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then, update the software database.

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install flatpak

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```